# Use EclipseLink in Spring 3.2.5 (Pet Clinic project)

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink

I am running the Pet Clinic sample project comes with Spring3.2.5. Everything is fine with Hibernate, I want to try out EclipseLink. Here is my business-config.xml

```
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter"
            p:database="${jpa.database}" p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}"/> 
        --> 
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        <property name="database" value="mydb" />
        </bean>                        
    </property>
    <!-- gDickens: BOTH Persistence Unit and Packages to Scan are NOT compatible, persistenceUnit will win -->
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mydb"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mydb"/>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction manager for a single JPA EntityManagerFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
      p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>


<!--
    Post-processor to perform exception translation on @Repository classes (from native
    exceptions such as JPA PersistenceExceptions to Spring's DataAccessException hierarchy).
-->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

and I am keep getting:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/business-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter#62d24dc7' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter] while setting bean property 'jpaVendorAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter#62d24dc7' defined in class path resource [spring/business-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/PersistenceProvider
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Check your classpath to make sure all the needed jars are there: `NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/PersistenceProvider`

Comment: Just checked, i have the right jar in my class path and I am able to access this class from my code.

Answer (score 0):

Used Maven/POM.xml in pull Eclipselink.jar instead of including in the java build path manually fixed my problem.